# problem to play sound

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

***i have develop one application(in 1.5) in which `2 activity` stay there. in first activity i have put `background sound`.and in second activity i have put `animal sound`.now when i am play it in emulator it work fine but when i have test it in android device version 2.1,i got force close error.***

**Take action:**

1. while i have remove background sound and continue with animal sound
   it work fine in device.
2. while i have remove animal sound and continue with background sound
   it work fine in device.
3. set rebuild automatically.
4. clean it again and again.

**I cant able to get exactly what error are raise, because it is happen only in device.**

*i have use to play sound ::*

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.touch_and_show);
mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: do you have the device with you ?? if yes please make debug and then post the Log error

Comment: paste the logcat error content

Comment: i cant able to past logcat becase error raise in device not emulator.

Comment: if you know that how to get error in device so suggest me

Comment: are you using service??
then in **onCreate** : mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.touch_and_show);

in  **onStart** : mPlayer.start();

Comment: @hanry ya i know it very well

Comment: see: private void startPlay(String file) {
  Log.i("Selected: ", file);
  
  selelctedFile.setText(file);
  seekbar.setProgress(0);
    
  player.stop();
  player.reset();
  
  try {
   player.setDataSource(file);
   player.prepare();
   player.start();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());
  playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
  
  updatePosition();
  
  isStarted = true;
 }

Comment: now i found , i have raise problem because i have use background sound in first activity play during the entire application(in loop). and in second activity 6 sound play. i think it is memory problem. how can i destroy sound?

Comment: finally i have got my solution. i ha stop previous sound and play current by this i can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.touch_and_show);
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();
```